# pg_replication_origin_status returns NULL external_id

Tags: postgresql, replication

When i run

```
pdns=# select * from pg_replication_origin_status ;
 local_id | external_id | remote_lsn | local_lsn
----------+-------------+------------+-----------
        2 |             | 0/7D56538  | 0/0
        3 |             | 0/7D563E8  | 0/0
(2 rows)
```

What does it mean and how to fix that .
Logical replication was stopped.

Comment: Check the PostgreSQL server log, there are more details there on why logical replication has stopped.